# Cassandra backup: plain copy disk files vs snapshots

Tags: cassandra

We are planning to deploy a Cassandra cluster with 100 virtual nodes.
To store maximally 1TB (compressed) data on each node. We're going to use (host-) local SSD disks.

The infrustructure team is used to plainly backing up the whole partitions.
We've come across Cassandra Snapshots.

What is the difference between **plainly copying the whole disk** vs. **Cassandra snapshots**?

 - Is there a **size** difference? 
 - Using whole partition backups, also **unnecessarily** saves uncompressed data that are being **compacted**, is that the motive behind snapshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few benefits of using snapshots:

1. Snapshot command will flush the memtable to ssTables and then creates snapshots.
2. Nodetool can be used to restore the snapshots.
3. Incremental backup functionality can also be leveraged.
4. Snapshots create hardlink of your data so it is much faster.

**Note:** Cassandra can only restore data from a snapshot when the table schema exists. It is recommended that you also backup the schema.
In both it is to be made sure that operation (snapshot or plain copy) run at same time on all the nodes.

Comment: Do snapshots always use hardlinks? So they take up no space?

Comment: After compaction, unnecessary files are removed, is there any commands to delete unnecessary hardlinks?

Comment: No you have to remove the old snapshots when you take new snapshot using clearsnapshots, if not using incremental

Comment: Answer to my question: snapshots yet need to be copied